# Can you help me understand this simple PHP function, please?

Tags: php

I would like to know how this function works so I can re-write it in ColdFusion. I've never programmed in PHP. **I think**, the function checks if $string is 11 numbers in length.

1. But how is it doing it?
2. Why is it using a loop instead of a simple len() function?

I read about str_pad(), and understand it. But what is the function of the loop iteration `$i` as a third argument? What's it doing?

```
if($this->check_fake($cpf, 11)) return FALSE;

function check_fake($string, $length)
{
   for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
   $fake = str_pad("", $length, $i);
   if($string === $fake) return(1);
   }
}
```

The function is meant to validate a CPF, the Brazilian equivalent of a US SSN #. The CPF is 11 characters in length. Basically, I need to know what it's doing so I can write the function in Coldfusion.

If it's just a length, can't it be `if (len(cpf) != 11) return false;` ?

Here is the entire code snippet if it interests you:

```
    <?
    /*
    *@ Class VALIDATE - It validates Brazilian CPF/CNPJ numbers 
    *@ Developer: André Luis Cupini - andre@neobiz.com.br
    ************************************************************/
    class VALIDATE
    {
        /*
        *@ Remove ".", "-", "/" of the string
        *****************************************************/
        function cleaner($string)
        {
            return $string = str_replace("/", "", str_replace("-", "", str_replace(".", "", $string)));
        }

        /*
        *@ Check if the number is fake
        *****************************************************/
        function check_fake($string, $length)
        {
            for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                $fake = str_pad("", $length, $i);
                if($string === $fake) return(1);
            }
        }

        /*
        *@ Validates CPF
        *****************************************************/
        function cpf($cpf) 
        {
            $cpf = $this->cleaner($cpf);
            $cpf = trim($cpf);
            if(empty($cpf) || strlen($cpf) != 11) return FALSE;
            else {
                if($this->check_fake($cpf, 11)) return FALSE;
                else {
                    $sub_cpf = substr($cpf, 0, 9);
                    for($i =0; $i <=9; $i++) {
                        $dv += ($sub_cpf[$i] * (10-$i));
                    }
                    if ($dv == 0) return FALSE; 
                    $dv = 11 - ($dv % 11); 
                    if($dv > 9) $dv = 0;
                    if($cpf[9] != $dv) return FALSE;

                    $dv *= 2;
                    for($i = 0; $i <=9; $i++) {
                        $dv += ($sub_cpf[$i] * (11-$i));
                    }
                    $dv = 11 - ($dv % 11); 
                    if($dv > 9) $dv = 0;
                    if($cpf[10] != $dv) return FALSE;
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but there's a Wikipedia article on [CPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas) that has validation pseudocode - I'd be *very* tempted to use this rather than the PHP code above.

Comment: Isn't it better do implement an algorithm which calculates and checks the control digits? People may try things like 12345678901 which will be entirely correct according to your algorithm. Check Wikipedia for an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_Pessoas_F%C3%ADsicas

Comment: @middaparka and @Emil Vikstrom, isn't the the main function in my code snippet doing that exactly?

Comment: My point is that by slavishly translating the PHP code, you'll duplicate any errors that may be present. As the validation isn't that complex, it might be easier simply to implement this yourself. (Then again, you may of course introduce bugs with your own implementation, but this could well happen in he translation process anyway.)

Comment: Just to make clear that the only invalid CPF numbers are 00000000000 and 99999999999. All other common inputs are VALID and some of them even got issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With comments:

```
function check_fake($string, $length)
{
    // for all digits
    for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) 
    {
        // create a $length characters long string, consisting of
        // $length number of the number $i
        // e.g. 00000000000
        $fake = str_pad("", $length, $i);
        // return true if the provided CPN is equal
        if($string === $fake) return(1);
    }
}
```

In short, it tests to see if the provided string is just the same digit repeated $length times.

Answer (score 2):

it basically makes sure the number isn't:

```
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
44444444444
55555555555
```

etc...